# PHP If i click on my button i want to send value to database

Tags: php, sql, database

```
if (isset($_POST['true']) || isset($_POST['false'])) {
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM score_user";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO score_user (uGekozen)
VALUES ('T')";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

When i click the button true or false i want to send T into my score_user

Comment: replace "T" with a properly sanitized $score value

Comment: what is your error msg, did you write logic for the button??

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_POST['true']) || isset($_POST['false'])) {
$sql = "INSERT INTO score_user(uGekozen) VALUES ('T')";
$result =  $conn->query($sql);
```